# Multiple editions under one author in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, texshop

I am using TexShop. The document class is `scrbook`. In the bibliography, there are a few texts under one author. For some unknown reason, since yesterday the author's name gets repeated and some texts occur under one while others under other. I have run BibTeX several times. If I get this fixed then the footnote no.s instead of starting from one on each page, get continuous numbering. So I can't get all texts under one author and footnote no.s restarting every page. Need help.

```
\documentclass[11pt,english]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[paperwidth=16cm,paperheight=24cm]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}


\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Gentium Plus}


% !BIB program = biber


\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{footnote}


\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=philosophy-modern,
publocformat=loccolonpub,
inbeforejournal=true]{biblatex}



\addbibresource{mybiblio.bib}
```

Here are the bib entries:

```
@book{amara_namalinganus!asana_1914,
  author = {Amarasiṃha},
  location =     {Trivandrum},
  title =    {The Nâmaliṅgânus(!)âsana of Amarasimha. With the
                  Commentary T(!)îkâsarvaswa of
                  Vandyaghat(!)îya-Sarvânanda. Parts I and {IV}},
  editor =   {Sâstrî, T. Gaṇapati},
  series =   {Trivandruṃ Sanskrit Series},
  number =   {{XXXVIII}, {LII}},
  date =     1914,
}

@book{amara_namalinganus!asana_1915,
  author = {Amarasiṃha},
  location =     {Trivandrum},
  title =    {The Nâmalingânus(!)âsana of Amarasimha. With the two
                  commentaries Amarakosodghâṭana of Kshîrasvâmin and
                  T(!)îkâsarvasva of
                  Vandyaghat(!)îya-Sarvânanda. Parts {II} and {III}},
  editor =   {Sâstrî, T. Gaṇapati},
  series =   {Trivandrum Sanskrit Series},
  number =   {{XLIII}, {LI}},
  date =     1915,
}

@book{oka_namalinganusasana_1913,
  author = {Amarasiṃha},
  location =     {Poona},
  title =    {The Nâmalingânuśâsana: (Amarakosha) of Amarasimha
                  with the Commentary (Amarakoshodghâtana) of
                  Kshîrasvâmin},
  editor =   {Oka, K. G.},
  date =     1913,
}

@book{amara_namalinganusasana_1929,
  author = {Amarasiṃha},
location =   {Bombay},
  edition =  {Fifth edition},
  title =    {The Nâmalingânuśâsana (Amarakosha) of
                  Amarasimha. With the Commentary (Vyâkhyâsudhâ or
                  Ramâśramî) of Bhânuji Dîkshit. Edited with Notes},
   reviser =     {Paṇśīkar, Wāsudev Laxmaṇ Śāstrī},
  date =     1929,
}
```

Comment: You say you have run bibtex, but you need to run biber.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't quite understand what exactly is there problem here. Can you rephrase your question, include a screenshot of what you see now and explain exactly what you would like to see instead (possibly with a mock-up picture of the desired output). It would also help greatly if you could turn the code posted so far into a compilable example document (an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). Currently the code is missing the `\begin{document}...\end{document}` body, so we don't really know what you are doing.

Comment: That said, I just ran https://gist.github.com/moewew/348f8601e2988d76228dbe665dc89a58 (a minimal example based on your code) and it compiled to https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkfBT.png in the bibliography and https://i.stack.imgur.com/FR57a.png in the footnotes on p. 2 (the numbers restart)

Comment: @Johannes_B, sorry, I meant to say, I ran biber several times.

Comment: @moewe, There are two problems. One is with bibliography. There are six editions of a text written by Amarasimha. So these should be grouped under his name. But instead, first 5 get get grouped under him, then again appears the author's name Amarasiṃha and below it the last edition. Does this make the question clearer? Sorry, I could not insert the screenshot.

Comment: @moewe, after running biber and xelatex several times, the issue of bibliography gets solved (all the 6 entries get grouped under Amarasiṃha); but then, in the main text, footnote numbers become continuous (instead of starting from 1 on each page). I can't understand the relation between the two issues.

Comment: In my tests the footnotes reset on each page. You'll need to edit the code in your question to become a fully compilable example document that reproduces the issue you are seeing with as little code as possible. There code you have shown so far should work as intended, so there must be something else going on here that we can't see so far.

Comment: Consider accepting and upvoting the great answer?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed off-site at https://gist.github.com/moewew/348f8601e2988d76228dbe665dc89a58 the OP was asking about situations where the author/editor name is repeated after a page break as in

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=philosophy-modern,
publocformat=loccolonpub,
inbeforejournal=true]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\nocite{aristotle:anima,aristotle:physics,
  aristotle:poetics,aristotle:rhetoric,
  aksin,geer,chiu,angenendt,herrmann,
  knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,knuth:ct:d,knuth:ct:e,
  sigfridsson,nussbaum,worman}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: page 1]

[image: page 2]

This is intentional as `biblatex` thinks it is useful to repeat the name on the new page for the avoidance of doubt, it also saves your readers having to flip back to the last page to check the name.

Ultimately, this is implemented in the bibmacro `bbx:dashcheck` (defined in `authoryear.bbx`)

```
\newbibmacro*{bbx:dashcheck}[2]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldequals{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}}
    and
    not test \iffirstonpage
    and
    (
       not bool {bbx@inset}
       or
       test {\iffieldequalstr{entrysetcount}{1}}
    )
  }
    {#1}
    {#2}}
```

with `\iffirstonpage`. `\iffirstonpage` obeys the `pagetracker` option, so if you don't like it at all that `biblatex` restarts certain things on a new page (think also "ibid." citations), you can completely disable this feature with `pagetracker=false`. If you just want this particular macro to ignore `pagetracker`, remove the relevant test

```
\renewbibmacro*{bbx:dashcheck}[2]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldequals{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}}
    and
    (
       not bool {bbx@inset}
       or
       test {\iffieldequalstr{entrysetcount}{1}}
    )
  }
    {#1}
    {#2}}
```

Note that `pagetracker` is aware of double/single-sided printing, so you may see different behaviours for even and odd pages in double-sided printing where a spread of an even and an odd page are treated as a single unit.

Comment: +1: Great answer! How am I the first upvote?!